# ngFor trackBy combined string Performance

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm working on a chatting app using angular10+rxjs. I'm looping through all the recent visitors im chatting with *ngFor. The references for the visitors changes quite frequently, however usually the changes in the displayed fields are not that frequent (things like the name, date, last message). So I though of using the trackBy and only track the visible items in the visitor tag. something like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let visitor of (visitors$ | async); trackBy:trackByVisitor" (click)="showThread(visitor);">
...
```

```
    trackByVisitor(index, visitor: Visitor){
        return visitor.id + visitor.name + visitor.last_message_created
                + visitor.unread_count + visitor.is_attended + visitor.agents;
    }
```

My questions is, would this affect performance in any way or considered as bad practice? since instead of having ngFor just checking references it's now checking a long string that can be like this `b34c550f-36e6-4700-8a2c-9afda7a734f3undefined2020-12-02 10:59:05.1405620trueda43c498-df61-4610-a0d1-80f4ccb71314`

[image]